# What's the problem and How can I resolve it in this code?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Question -

**Given a string s and an integer array indices of the same length.
The string s will be shuffled such that the character at the ith position moves to indices[i] in the shuffled string.
Return the shuffled string**

Input: s = "aiohn",  indices = `[3,1,4,2,0]`
, Correct Output: "nihao"
, My output : "hinoa"

Input: s = "aaiougrt", indices = `[4,0,2,6,7,3,1,5]`
, Correct Output: "arigatou"
, My output : "uairtoag"

```
class Solution {
    public String restoreString(String s, int[] indices) {
        
        String res= "";
        
        for(int i=0 ; i<s.length() ; i++){
            res+= s.charAt(indices[i]);
        }
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class Solution {
    public String restoreString(String s, int[] indices) {
        char[] chars = new char[s.length()];
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++){
            chars[indices[i]] = s.charAt(i);
        }
        
        return new String(chars);
    }
}
```

what you are doing is the opposite, the ith char in res is str.charAt(indices[i]);